# Split String in Reporting Services expression

Tags: string, reporting-services, split, ssrs-2008

I have a free text field that have full name of consultants.

e.g. Smith John

I would like to display in reporting services expression as John Smith.

i want to swap the name around, bring the first name first.

any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
=Right(Fields!name.Value, Len(Fields!name.Value) - InStr(Fields!name.Value, " "))
    & " "
    & Left(Fields!name.Value, InStr(Fields!name.Value, " ") - 1)
```